# blazor variable argument passing to onclick function

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to pass the int i into the button onclick function for each list item. I expected the "clickItem" function will receive 0..2 for correspondig list item. But it come out that it always receive 3 as argument. It seems that the variable i in the clickItem(i) is not evaluated at the time of render of the for loop. I have tried changing it to "clickItem(@i)" but it is still the same. What should I do? (I am using blazor server side, .net core 3 preview 5)

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            <li> item @i <button onclick=@(() => clickItem(i))>Click</button> </li>
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a classic problem, but slightly new in the context of Blazor.

You need to make a copy of `i` because otherwise the "[lambda captures the loop variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=lambda%20closing%20over%20the%20loop%20variable)". Capturing the copy is OK.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int localCopy = i;
    <li> item @i <button onclick=@(() => clickItem(localCopy))>Click</button> </li>
}
```

Note that this is an issue with `for()` loops but not with `foreach()`, and only on the right hand side of a `=>`.

Comment: Thanks Henk, it works. But I don't understand the underlying difference. Why the "copy" and "i" will be treated differently? Is there some reference for me to further study?

Comment: See my answer here for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278600/calling-function-from-generated-button-in-blazor/55278788#55278788

Comment: You can google " lambda 'captures' the loop variable" for dozens of Q+A, mostly on SO. That's why I didn't make this answer  too long.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it worked. Hope it seems helpful to you.

```
 @foreach (var item in ListOfUser)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                    <td>
                        <button @onclick="(() => GetDetail(item.UserId)) "> Click</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Comment: Yes a foreach() does not have the same problem as for(). But in the question, `i` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `foreach` loop instead, you can refer to the example below.

You declare a variable called `index` inside the loop which is used to store the index of the current item in the loop using the `IndexOf` method on the `items` list. This index is then passed as an argument to the `clickItem` function when the button is clicked.

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    var index = items.IndexOf(item);
    <li> item @item 
        <button onclick=@(() => clickItem(index))>Click</button>
    </li>
}
```