# Prevent checkbox (or InputCheckBox) to be unchecked - Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I extracted my issue to the simple code, that just doesn't work as expected:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked=@Visible  @onchange="args=> {Visible=true;}"/>

@code
{
 public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;
}
```

([Available online](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wPascIOX59iMhW1e15))

For some reason I want the checkbox to stay checked even if I clicked it (unchecked it). I cannot figure that out even with `StateHasChanged()` or `InputCheckBox` element.

This may sound stupid thing to do, but as I said, it is extracted code from complex one, that makes sense. Disabling checkbox is not solution here.

Comment: What is the difference with disabling?  Functional or cosmetic?

Comment: Functional. I need the information, that it was meant to be changed.. But yeah, I can go with disabling somehow. But it's more about understanding why that doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Reset input field value if value is invalid in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901935/reset-input-field-value-if-value-is-invalid-in-blazor) for detailed explanation in a very similar question I answered a little while ago.

Basically, the DOM held by the Renderer looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked ....>
```

When you unclick the check box the actual browser DOM is now out of sync with the Renderer DOM.  The `onchange` event gets fired and the new value is passed to the event in the `ChangeEventArgs`.  It's still checked in the Renderer DOM, though unchecked in the Browser DOM.  You then set it to this for the next render:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked ....>
```

The Renderer DOM sees no difference, and therefore doesn't send an update to the Browser.  The code below forces that change by setting the Browser DOM to the unchecked state before reverting to the correct state.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col p-2 m-2">
        <input type="checkbox" checked=@Visible @onchange="OnChangeCheck" />
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2 m-2">
        <input type="checkbox" checked=@Visible @onchange="OnChangeCheck1" />
    </div>
</div>
    public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;

    async Task OnChangeCheck(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false;
        await Task.Yield();
        Visible = true;
    }

    async Task OnChangeCheck1(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: It's weird to have "unnecessary" Yield. But it works. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: It's not unnecessary.  Check https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5310624/Blazor-UI-Events-and-Rendering which explains the render process.  With it the Blazor Event Handler can do it's double render act, and the Renderer gets Synchronization Thread time to service the Render Queue.  Without it you only get one render event when OnChangeCheck completes - the whole sequence is sync and the Renderer gets no thread time to service any `StateHasChanged` requests on the Render Queue until it completes.

Comment: The code demonstrated in answer assumes the "Visible" property remains synced to the client state.  Might improve readability and robustness of the code if instead of setting Visible to false or true, you set it to (bool)args.Value since that's the value received from the browser event.   Doing it this way guarantees you sync up the server DOM to what's shown in the browser before invoking Task.Yield().

Comment: Also helps readability as it expresses code intent better.

Comment: @JamesHoux - I agree.  I've updated the answer ;-)

Comment: "Visible = false;"  should be changed to "Visible = (bool)e.Value;".  This has to happen before Task.Yield(), because the goal is to make the server DOM match the client state before proceeding with rest of code.

Comment: I've reverted the answer to the original.  Read the question.  how to force the checkbox to selected no matter what the user does.

Comment: Ah... very good observation.  My Mistake. I misinterpreted what the code was supposed to be doing because I was dealing with slightly different problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler if you add another hidden field with the value you want binded to the field model.
Then the checkbox can be disabled because you don't need the value.