# blazor force full render instead of differential render

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to display images using [this masonry js package](https://masonry.desandro.com/) but I am having difficulties.

I have an image upload form. The user clicks a button to bind images to `Model.Images`, and then they get displayed on the page. The user can bind multiple batches of images before submitting the form. Each time the user binds another batch of images to `Model.Images`, the previous batch is persisted - that is to say, I do not truncate `Model.Images` before binding the images from the next batch.

The problem I am seeing is: the masonry js script needs to be re-triggered every time `Model.Images` gets added to, because the js only applies to the most recently-rendered view. However, it seems every time I force `StateHasChanged();` the images from the most recently-added batch overlap the previous images, so I see this:

**after first batch of images is bound**
[image: after first batch of images is bound]

**after second batch of images is bound**
[image: after second batch of images is bound]

I think this has something to do with differential rendering. If I move the images to a helper object, truncate `Model.Images`, force `StateHasChanged()`, and then repopulate `Model.Images`, the images get displayed side by side properly. I most likely am just approaching this incorrectly. Can someone advise me how to achieve what I want without my hacky implementation? I pasted a simplified version of my code below - this the implementation that is producing the bad results pictured above.

**razor component**
(the `TriggerMasonry()` event gets called after `Model.Images` gets appended to.)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Images.Count; j++)
{
    var iCopy = i; //see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426146/323447
    var uri = $"data:{Model.Images[iCopy].ImageMimeType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Images[iCopy].ImageDataLarge.ToArray())}";

    <div class="grid-item" @ref=MasonryElement>
        <div class="card m-2 shadow-sm" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="@uri" class="card-img-top" alt="..." loading="lazy">
        </div>
    </div>
}


@code {
    ElementReference MasonryElement;

    private async void TriggerMasonry()
    {
        if (Model.Images.Where(x => x.ImageData != null).Any())
        {
            StateHasChanged();
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initMasonryDelay", MasonryElement);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**js**

```
function initMasonryDelay() {

    setTimeout(function () {

        // init Masonry
        var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true,
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
        });

        // layout Masonry after each image loads
        $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function () {
            $grid.masonry();
        });

    }, 150); //milliseconds
}
```

**css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
    width: 33.333%;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

/* To change the amount of columns on larger devices, uncomment the code below */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 33.333%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 20%;
    }
}


.grid-item {
    float: left;
}

    .grid-item img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

**----Another example for user @Brian_Parker----**
I tried to apply your suggestions but I'm still not having any luck. I clearly must not understand how JS interoperability works with blazor components. I think my problem has to do with not getting how `@ref` works. I sized the array like you suggested, but I'm just creating a proper-length array filled with null refs. I realize this must be wrong, but I am not sure what to fill them with - I tried replacing `object[] imageRefs` with a `ElementReference[] imageRefs` and filling `imageRefs` with `ElementReference[i].Id` and passing that to the JS function, but it didn't change the overall behavior of the page. I reverted to baseline for the sake of making my code easier to digest.

I pasted below a different example, that might be easier to understand in a UI context. If you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong here, I'd greatly appreciate it:

I have another component in which I'm trying to apply the Masonry JS to a dynamically-generated list of images. Basic overview: On load, 10 images are pulled from the server and rendered. When the user clicks a "load more" button, 10 more images are pulled from the server and get rendered. I am seeing the same issue where the 2nd round of images is laid over the first round.

My razor component:

```
<!-- Masonry -->
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < pagedThings.Data.Count; i++)
    {
        var iCopy = i; //see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426146/323447
        <div @key="@pagedThings.Data[iCopy]" class="grid-item" @ref=imageRefs[iCopy]>
            <div class="card">
                @{ 
                    var mimeType = pagedThings.Data[iCopy].ImageThings.FirstOrDefault().ImageMimeTypeLarge;
                    var imgData = pagedThings.Data[iCopy].ImageThings.FirstOrDefault().ImageDataLarge;
                }
                <img src="@String.Format("data:" + mimeType + ";base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(imgData))" loading="lazy">
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<!-- Load more button -->
<button class="btn" type="button" @onclick="GetMoreThings">
    <span>Load more</span>
</button>

@code {
    PagedResponse<List<Thing>> pagedThings { get; set; }
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private int currentPageSize = 10;
    object[] imageRefs;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            //load Things
            await LoadThings();
        }
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private async Task LoadThings()
    {
        pagedThings = await ThingService.GetByPageAsync($"api/Things/GetThingsByPage?pageNumber={currentPage}&pageSize={currentPageSize}");
        imageRefs = new object[pagedThings.Data.Count()];
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("masonryAppendDelay", imageRefs[imageRefs.Length - 1]);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task GetMoreThings()
    {
        currentPage++;

        var newData = await ThingService.GetByPageAsync($"api/Things/GetThingsByPage?pageNumber={currentPage}&pageSize={currentPageSize}");
        foreach (var item in newData.Data)
        {
            pagedThings.Data.Add(item);
        }
        imageRefs = new object[pagedThings.Data.Count()];
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("masonryAppendDelay", imageRefs[imageRefs.Length - 1]);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

My JS:

```
function masonryAppendDelay(element) {

    setTimeout(function () {

        // init Masonry
        var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: element,
            percentPosition: true,
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
        });

        // layout Masonry after each image loads
        $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function () {
            $grid.masonry();
            //$grid.masonry('layout');
        });

    }, 200); //milliseconds
}
```

My css is the same as in the original post.

Comment: You are reszing imageRefs = new object[pagedThings.Data.Count()]; but not populating it with any data. I am also not understang how imageRefs is being applied.

Comment: Hey @sion_corn do you have an overview of a complete blazor implementation using masonry js? ( a demo site I mean ) I would love to use it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are capturing a reference in loop. This will only assign the final loops reference. You will have to size an array to capture the references once you know who many iterations there is. `refs = new object[someValue]`

Your Trigger masonry function will then have to traverse the reference list.

```
<div @key="@Model.Images[iCopy]" class="grid-item" @ref=refs[iCopy]>
        <div class="card m-2 shadow-sm" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="@uri" class="card-img-top" alt="..." loading="lazy">
        </div>
</div>


@code { 
    object[] refs;
}
```

Call your java script for each reference after it has been rendered.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        foreach (var obj in refs)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("masonryAppendDelay", obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this does not make a difference in my case.

Comment: The problem seems to come from the JS - it seems to only work if it is called once: `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initMasonryDelay");` - if I call it for the first time only after the **second** image is bound, then both images are neatly arranged in a masonry layout. if I call the JS each time an image gets bound, then I see the overlap issue.

Comment: @sion_corn I think I have spotted the issue.

Comment: @brian_parker thanks for your reply. I still don't quite get it - I updated the OP with another example that shows my attempt to implement your suggestions. Unfortunately I am still unable to produce the behavior that I'm after.

Comment: @sion_corn You need to call your JavaScript for each reference. The changes you made still only call it once and for the last item.

Comment: i was able to get it to work following your advice - thanks.

Comment: hey @BrianParker I'm also trying to get this going... but just starting with Blazor, I'm stuck with your solution example ( as in, not sure how to get that refs[iCopy] variable initialised correctly ). I'm trying to get this codepin of mine converted to blazor: https://codepen.io/depechie/pen/xxqdJdW could you maybe expand the code example a bit more?

Comment: @Depechie Can you put your blazor code in a BlazorRepl.com or somewhere similar and I'll help.